# how to commit offset in kafka topic using OffsetCommitRequest?

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I went through https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka
link and came to know Kafka provided new topic which only deals with offset handling for specific partition in a topic.

I created new topic and disabled only auto.commit.enable property as false.
using Kafka Tool 1.0 Beta2 I can check the offsets and messages on the topic. now the offset is still and need commit programmatically.

1. I wanted to know if OffsetCommitRequest Api example as above commits
   the offset or not as I am unable to commit using same example.
2. Another thing that do I need to use SimpleConsumer Example to commit
   the offset on Kafka topic. will it not commit on zookeeper ?
3. Lastly what is the purpose of ConsumerConnecter then ?

I want to consume message only once and then keep track of offsets as well.

I am using Kafka 0.8.2.1, and also integrating it with Apache Camel. so will be using camel-kafka as well.